# How to send velocity to pixhawk with Mavros?

Tags: ros, velocity, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

after searching a lot and don't get a solution I would like a help. I am a new user of Mavros package and I have some doubts about it. My setup for tests is:

1 Pixhawk with ArduCopter V3.2.1Quad firmware, 1 ESC 20A SkyWalker, 1 motor, 1 GPS+Compass, 1 radio receiver and 1 battery. I installed mavros on Indigo and ubuntu 14.04.

I want to start sending a simple command of linear velocity to pixhawk, for example vx = 1 m/s.

I typed the commands bellow in sequence:

1. sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0
2. roslaunch mavros px4.launch
3. rosrun mavros mavsafety arm
4. and my code: rosrun copter velocity

After that nothing happened. The the motor spun with default velocity of the node mavsafety arm and not with desired velocity.

What topic should I publish this message?

I checked the topic /mavros/setpoint_attitude/cmd_vel and the value that I set in the source code was there.

So, where is the mistake? Should I do some setup before to run?

I read at some forum people talking about some setup that we have to do...but is not clear for me.

Can anyone show a piece of code that make what I want or give me a tips?

Thank you!

I wrote a code trying to do this but without successful.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include "geometry_msgs/TwistStamped.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ros::init(argc, argv, "comun");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
 
   ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::TwistStamped>("/mavros/setpoint_attitude/cmd_vel",100);
   ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

   geometry_msgs::TwistStamped msg;

   while(ros::ok()){
       msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
       msg.header.seq=1;
       msg.twist.linear.x = 1;
       msg.twist.angular.x = 1;

       chatter_pub.publish(msg);
       ros::spinOnce();
       loop_rate.sleep();
   }    
   return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207097/how-to-send-velocity-to-pixhawk-with-mavros?/) by [alexandre28](https://answers.ros.org/users/22150/alexandre28/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did which you suggest,

2. roslaunch mavros apm.launch
3. rosrun mavros mavsafety arm
4. rosrun mavros mavsys mode -c GUIDED
   that resulted: Mode changed
5. and ran my code (with just yaw rotation -> twist.angular.z)

but nothing happened. The motor is spinning with default velocity when the pixhawk is armed.

The topic that am I publishing is correct? (/mavros/setpoint_attitude/cmd_vel)

---

Originally posted by [alexandre28](https://answers.ros.org/users/22150/alexandre28/) with karma: 36 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-04-15**:
Topic correct (you may check by `rqt_graph`). Also try position sp. Note that SP support is new in APM, not sure that it exist in latest stable release.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

may be you should try:
/mavros/setpoint_velocity/cmd_vel (geometry_msgs/TwistStamped)

Velocity setpoint.

---

Originally posted by [srikanthmalla](https://answers.ros.org/users/26013/srikanthmalla/) with karma: 11 on 2016-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1